# CMake include header file in different directory

Tags: c++, cmake

So I have a directory that's formatted as follows:

```
Project: 
- src 
   - a.cpp 
   - b.cpp 
   - c.cpp 
- include 
   - h.cpp 
   - h.hpp
```

How would I get CMake to include `h.hpp` in the files in the source folder? I tried doing `include_directories(include)` but CMake is still unable to find the file. I also tried changing the include directive in a.cpp to `#include "../include/h.hpp"`. However, none of these solutions have worked.

EDIT:

The output is:

```
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target a
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target c
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target b
[build] [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/b.dir/src/b.cpp.o
[build] [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c.dir/src/c.cpp.o
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/src/a.cpp.o
[build] [ 66%] Linking CXX executable a
[build] [ 83%] Linking CXX executable c
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable b
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/a.dir/src/a.cpp.o: in function `func(...)':
[build] ../a.cpp:55: undefined reference to `func(...)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: a.cpp:58: undefined reference to `func(...)'
```

Note that func is a function with an implementation provided in `h.cpp`.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
  CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

project(proj)


find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

link_libraries(
    fmt::fmt CUDA::nvrtc CUDA::cuda_driver CUDA::cudart
)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/a.cpp)
add_executable(b ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/b.cpp)
add_executable(c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/c.cpp)
```

Comment: We cannot help you without viewing your `CMakeLists.txt` and **exact output**.

Comment: "undefined reference to `func(...)" Is a linker error. That has nothing to do with including headers, but all to do with what you are linking.

Comment: why would it be failing to link? shouldn't I just need to specify ```h.hpp``` in ```a.cpp```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `h.cpp` as a source for each executable that uses functions from `h.hpp`:

```
add_executable(a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/a.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/h.cpp)
add_executable(b ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/b.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/h.cpp)
add_executable(c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/c.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/h.cpp)
```

As you have said,

> func is a function with an implementation provided in h.cpp

so you need to add that implementation to your executables

Comment: Oh I see, have to specify the cpp not the hpp. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and also, to make #include "h.hpp" work, you can add `target_include_directories(a PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/h.hpp)` after `add_executable`s (for each executable)

Comment: And you can omit `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` in `add_executable`, etc. if your `CMakeLists.txt` is in the root of the project (you can do like this: `add_executable(a src/a.cpp include/h.cpp)`)

Comment: Hmm that's a good tip, perhaps I'll give it a go. Thanks!